# Add general arguments in an abstract method (Java)

Tags: java

Say I have an abstract class called "Subsystem.java" and I have a class that extends it called "Drive.java". In Subsystem.java, I have a method called initialize with no arguments. How do I Override that method in Drive.java and add arguments? In other words, I want to be able to override a method with no arguments into one that has arguments. Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible. It is not an override, it's an overload. To override, the methods must have the same signature - same name, number and types of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not an [override](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding), but an [overload](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). You still couldn't create an instance from `Drive`, since it would have an unimplemented abstract method.

*Overrides* have the exact same signatures.
*Overloads* have the same name, but different parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

You can not override as like you describe.

When a method in a subclass has the same name, same parameters or signature and same return type(or sub-type) as a method in its super-class, then the method in the subclass is said to override the method in the super-class.

you can refer below link for more information about overriding a method in Java.
[Method overriding in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/)

or you can also refer Oracle Java documentation
[Oracle Java document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)